# Query was empty mysql php variable from jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, variables

I have a javascript that loads the contents of a DIV when checking a Checkbox and passes a variable.

I retrieve the variable with `$color = $_GET['color'];` and then I do a few IFs to pick my query:

```
if ($color != '') 
{
    if ($sortBy != '')
    {
        $items = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item_descr  WHERE color_base1 = '$color' ORDER BY '$sortBy' DESC");
    }
    else 
    { 
        $items = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 = $color");
        echo $color;
        $result = mysql_query($items) or die(mysql_error()); 
    }
}
```

Every time the $result is returning "Quert was empty" even if $color contains a value.

Note: I have tried to put $color in the query like this too: '$color' and also '".$color."'. Didn´t work
Would you have any idea of what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried already to use this SQL directly in phpMyAdmin or somewhere else? Does it work with `WHERE color_base1='#92462f'` (change the color value to a value that is in the DB)? Does it work without the WHERE-part of the clause?

Comment: Where is the code that prints "Query was empty"?

Comment: @ lars - Yes, it works directly in myAdmin. Its not a matter of the code, since the color is a VARCHAR... Any other suggestions? I don't think the syntax is bad, since it works when I don't send the jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simpler code:

```
if ($sortBy != '')
    $query = "SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 = '$color' ORDER BY $sortBy DESC";
else 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 = '$color'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

I removed the quotes around `$sortBy`, I added quotes around `$color`.

Answer (score 0):

Variables should be quoted `'` or `"`

```
$items = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 = '$color'");
```

or for better readability

```
$items = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 = ".$color);
```

and remove `$result` as `$items` will return true or false

Comment: I have tried all that but even when I just SELECT * without any WHERE, it doesn't work... Maybe it's because I am reloading a DIV?